# How to optimize the performance of the following SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

For the following query , I tried creating index on table tmp.req_index_cont_t  with columns indcont_key_1 and ind_no but still optimizer is performing full table scan , I am not getting how to resolve this issue , please guide :

```
CREATE INDEX tmp.REQ_CONT_T_IDX 
            ON tmp.req_index_cont_t (ind_no, indcont_key_1);

select distinct
            rit.item_no as item_no,
            rit.item_type as item_type,    
            rit.ind_no as ind_no,
            rit.delete_date as req_ind_delete_date,
            indcnt.delete_date as req_ind_cont_delete_date
from
    tmp.req_index_cont_t indcnt,
    tmp.req_index_t rit
where    rit.ind_no             = indcnt.ind_no
    and   indcnt.indcont_key_1 <> 'DN'
    and   rit.ind_state         = 'Approved'
group by    rit.item_no,
            rit.item_type,
            rit.ind_no,
            indcnt.delete_date,
            rit.delete_date ;
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables; the `CREATE INDEX` statements for any indexes; and the `EXPLAIN PLAN` for your query.

Comment: Why do you use `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` all the columns in the same statement? You can remove the `GROUP BY` clause (or, alternately, the `DISTINCT` keyword) and the results will not change as both are doing the same function.

Comment: Please, in addition to the table definition also add an **actual** execution plan collected via `select * from dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'ALL ALLSTATS LAST')` executed in the same session right after your original query. This will include **actual** rowcounts processed at each step to identify cardinalities.

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, instead of the comma-separated tables from the 1980s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough information here to answer your question. Why do you think a full table scan is not the best option for this query? I assume you're upset that it's doing a full table scan on `req_index_cont_t` because that's the one you put an index on.

As an educated guess, I'd say it's because you have `indcnt.delete_date` in the select list but not the index. That means Oracle will have to fetch the entire row in question and has decided against using the index.